# Obtener dato de la celda de una tabla html con javascript sin jquery

Tags: javascript

Buenas amigos tengo un pequeño problema, estoy haciendo un crud simple y en la parte del eliminar lo que deseo hacer es obtener el código de cada fila de la tabla, presionando cada boton eliminar, para poder borrar cada registro.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado tratando de desarrollar esa parte del crud pero no he podido, solo puedo obtener el código de la primera fila. ¿Cómo podría obtener cada código al presionar cada boton Eliminar de las filas? Tengo esto en mi código javascript.

```
document.getElementById("btnEliminar").addEventListener("click", function(){
  eliminarPersona();
});

function eliminarPersona(){
 let indice = document.getElementById("btnEliminar").parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
 alert(document.getElementById("tablaPersona").rows[indice].cells[0].innerHTML);
}
```

Los datos los traigo de una bd y los muestro de la sgte manera.

```
<div class="container mt-5" id="frmTabla">
    <table class="table" id="tablaPersona">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Dni</th>
                <th>Foto</th>
                <th>Opciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <?php
                for ($i=0; $i < count($resultado); $i++) { 
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $resultado[$i]["codigo"] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $resultado[$i]["nombre"] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $resultado[$i]["dni"] ?></td>
                        <td>Foto</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Modificar</button>
                            <button id="btnEliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="btnEliminar">Eliminar</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

yo te puedo recomendar que a tu botón eliminar le agregues el atributo `onclick="eliminar()"` y dentro de este como ya obtienes los datos de tu bd le mandes el id a la función algo a si:

```
<div class="container mt-5" id="frmTabla">
<table class="table" id="tablaPersona">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Dni</th>
            <th>Foto</th>
            <th>Opciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php
            for ($i=0; $i < count($resultado); $i++) { 
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $resultado[$i]["codigo"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $resultado[$i]["nombre"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $resultado[$i]["dni"] ?></td>
                    <td>Foto</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Modificar</button>
                        <button id="btnEliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="btnEliminar" onclick="eliminar(<?php echo $resultado[$i]["codigo"] ?>)">Eliminar</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>
function eliminar(id){
  alert("click en la fila con el código: "+id);
  //lo que necesites hacer

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras hacer lo siguiente:

- Dale a todos los botones de eliminación la misma clase
- Cada botón generale un `id` único
- Obtienes con `quuerySelectorAll` todos los botones que tengan la misma clase
- Iteras todos los botones contenidos en la variable por medio de un `foreach`
- A cada botón obtenido en las iteraciones dale un *lsitener* en el evento `click`
- Para saber que botón fue el presionado puedes acceder a la propiedad `id` de la variable `boton`

Obtener las celdas como lo llevas es un buen camino, pero que sería mas simple si les das una clase que te haga mas fácil solo obtener aquellas celdas cuya clase identifica a donde esta el botón de eliminación.

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Botón</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><button id="uno" class="eliminacion">Eluminar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td><button id="dos" class="eliminacion">Eluminar</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    Botón presionado <span></span>
    <script>
        let eliminacion = document.querySelectorAll(".eliminacion")
        
        eliminacion.forEach((boton) => {
          boton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            document.querySelector("span").innerText = ` id: ${boton.id}`
          })
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por responder, me falto mencionar que los datos los traigo de una bd y se muestran por medio de un for junto con los botones, estos tienen el mismo id.

Comment: Bueno el primer punto a corregir es que no deben tener el mismo ID eso no es correcto, en todo caso que tengan en común la clase

Comment: @PAOLOGUERRERO dejame ver que puedo cambiar de la respuesta

Comment: Gracias amigo, acabo de agregar en mi pregunta como muestro los datos, espero sirva de algo y gracias nuevamente